# ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have created a function in `PostgreSQL` to insert to the following

```
  CREATE TABLE gtab83
(
  orderid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_gtab83_id'::regclass),
  acid integer,
  slno integer,
  orderdte date
)
```

and created `Function` is

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcInsert(iacid int,islno int,idate date) RETURNS int AS

$$

declare id_val int;

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO GTAB83 (acid,slno,orderdte) VALUES (iacid,islno,idate) RETURNING orderid 
into id_val;

return id_val;

END;

$$

  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- when a execute the above function

> select funcInsert(666,13,'2014-06-06'

- getting this error

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>       CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function procgtab83(integer,integer,date) line 3 at SQL statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create or replace function funcinsert(iacid int, islno int, idate date)
returns int as $$

declare id_val int;

begin
    with i as (
        insert into gtab83 (acid,slno,orderdte)
        values (iacid,islno,idate)
        returning orderid
    )
    select orderid into id_val
    from i;
    return id_val;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It can be much simpler as plain sql

```
create or replace function funcinsert(iacid int, islno int, idate date)
returns int as $$

    insert into gtab83 (acid,slno,orderdte)
    values (iacid,islno,idate)
    returning orderid
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 4):

This code is working:

```
postgres=# create table xx(a int);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# create or replace function bu(int) returns int as 
             $$declare x int; 
             begin 
               insert into xx values($1) returning a into x; 
               return x; 
             end $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# select bu(10);
 bu 
────
 10
```

(1 row)

And because it is same code as your, I expect, so you use some very old Postgres. I remember similar bug in pg, but it is more than five years fixed.